# Trouble adding mouseover event listener to an SVG element

Tags: javascript

I cannot trigger an event for a svg element. I have the following jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1ahq5sa/

The html.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <svg class="video-nav-bar-container">
      <rect id="nav-bar" class="video-nav-bar" rx="20" ry="20"/>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

The script portion.

```
    var navBar = document.getElementById('nav-bar');

    navBar.addEventListener('moveover', function() {
      alert('It works!');
    });
```

I cannot get the mouseover event to fire and feeling like a complete noob. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: add a fiddle with issue

Comment: @Saurabh Does this code work for you? The fiddle is not working for my browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The event name is wrong, should be 'mouseover'.

```
navBar.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
      alert('It works!');
});
```